# Show $\bf{A}\times(\nabla \times A)= \frac{1}{2}\nabla(A \cdot A)-(A\cdot \nabla)A$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This is excercise 3.6.7 from Arfken. From the exercise just before we have: $$\bf \nabla(A\cdot B)=(A\times\nabla)\times B+(B\times\nabla)\times A+A(\nabla\cdot B)+B(\nabla\cdot A)$$ So with $\bf B=A$, we have: $$\bf \nabla(A\cdot A)=(A\times\nabla)\times A+(A\times\nabla)\times A+A(\nabla\cdot A)+A(\nabla\cdot A)$$
$$\bf \frac{1}{2} \nabla(A\cdot A)=(A\times\nabla)\times A+A(\nabla\cdot A)$$
$$\bf \frac{1}{2} \nabla(A\cdot A)-A(\nabla\cdot A)=(A\times\nabla)\times A$$

I am having difficulties with with getting from the last equality to the desired form, any help is appreciated.

Comment: $A\times B=-B\times A$ and hence $(A\times\nabla)\times A=-A\times (A\times\nabla)=A\times (\nabla\times A)$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Udalricus.S. Is it correct to use $\nabla$ as a vector in this manner?

Comment: You already write $A\times\nabla $ in the question, what is this? Is it the operator that you get by formally doing the cross product?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes. My only point with regards to Udalricus.S,'s comment was that even though $A \times B=-B \times A$, it is not necessarily true that $A \times \nabla= - \nabla \times A$.

Answer (score 3):

One way to show this relation is via an explicit calculation:
$$
A \times [\nabla \times A]
= \begin{pmatrix}A_x\\A_y\\A_z\end{pmatrix} \times \left[ \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x\\ \partial_y\\ \partial_z\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}A_x\\A_y\\A_z\end{pmatrix} \right]
= \begin{pmatrix}A_x\\A_y\\A_z\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}\partial_y A_z-\partial_z A_y\\ \partial_z A_x-\partial_x A_z\\ \partial_x A_y-\partial_y A_x\end{pmatrix}
\\= \begin{pmatrix}
A_y (\partial_x A_y-\partial_y A_x) - A_z (\partial_z A_x-\partial_x A_z) \\
A_z (\partial_y A_z-\partial_z A_y) - A_x (\partial_x A_y-\partial_y A_x) \\
A_x (\partial_z A_x-\partial_x A_z) - A_y (\partial_y A_z-\partial_z A_y) \\
\end{pmatrix}
\\
= \begin{pmatrix}(A_y \partial_x A_y + A_z \partial_x A_z) - (A_y \partial_y A_x + A_z \partial_z A_x) \\
(A_z \partial_y A_z + A_x \partial_y A_x) - (A_z \partial_z A_y + A_x \partial_x A_y) \\
(A_x \partial_z A_x + A_y \partial_z A_y) - (A_x \partial_x A_z + A_y \partial_y A_z) \\
\end{pmatrix}
\\= \begin{pmatrix}(A_x \partial_x A_x + A_y \partial_x A_y + A_z \partial_x A_z) - (A_x \partial_x A_x + A_y \partial_y A_x + A_z \partial_z A_x) \\
(A_x \partial_y A_x + A_y \partial_y A_y + A_z \partial_y A_z) - (A_x \partial_x A_y + A_y \partial_y A_y + A_z \partial_z A_y) \\
(A_x \partial_z A_x + A_y \partial_z A_y + A_z \partial_z A_z) - A_x \partial_x A_z + A_y \partial_y A_z + A_z \partial_z A_z) \\
\end{pmatrix}
\\
= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac12 \partial_x (A_x^2+A_y^2+A_z^2) - (A_x\partial_x+A_y\partial_y+A_z\partial_z) A_x \\
\frac12 \partial_y (A_x^2+A_y^2+A_z^2) - (A_x\partial_x+A_y\partial_y+A_z\partial_z) A_y \\
\frac12 \partial_z (A_x^2+A_y^2+A_z^2) - (A_x\partial_x+A_y\partial_y+A_z\partial_z) A_z \\
\end{pmatrix}
\\= \frac12 \nabla (A\cdot A) - (A\cdot\nabla) A
$$

Comment: Just a small side remark: for ordinary vectors there is the **Grassmann identity** $A\times(B\times C)=(A\cdot C)B-(A\cdot B)C$ which has no factor 1/2. It is nice to see from that direct proof where the factor 1/2 comes from when $B$ is a differential operator.

Comment: Generally, when $A,B,C$ do not commute, I get
$$A\times(B\times C) = A\cdot_{AC}BC - (A\cdot B)C,$$
where $\cdot_{AC}$ denotes that the inner product is taken between $A$ and $C$. If $B$ and $C$ commute then $$A\cdot_{AC}BC = A\cdot_{AC}CB=(A\cdot C)B$$
so that
$$A\times(B\times C) = (A\cdot C)B - (A\cdot B)C$$
just as @KurtG. writes.

Comment: Interestingly, the other [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del#Second_derivatives) $\nabla\times(\nabla\times A)=\nabla(\nabla\cdot A)-\Delta A$ has no factor 1/2. It is Grassmann like.