# how do i derive different equation from cross product of a curl

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

$\vec{a} \times (\nabla \times \vec{a}) = \frac{1}{2}\nabla{a^2}-(\vec{a} \cdot \nabla)\vec{a}$

How do I show this is true?
I attempted to use vector triple product rule however it yielded
$\vec{a} \times (\nabla \times \vec{a}) = \nabla{a^2}-(\vec{a} \cdot \nabla)\vec{a}$

I even tried to open up this formula to a component form. Yet i got no sensible answer.
Maybe I am missing something. Can someone help clarify this problem for me?

Comment: In $\nabla a^2$, does $a^2$ mean the norm squared of $a$?

Comment: The identity should be $$a\times(\nabla\times a) = \frac12 \nabla a^2 - (a\cdot\nabla)a.$$

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212674/show-bfa-times-nabla-times-a-frac12-nablaa-cdot-a-a-cdot-nabla